# How to use Seaborn's residplot after fitting regression?

Tags: linear-regression, seaborn

I have a simple linear multiple regression in Python that looks like this:

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x_cols,df['Volume'],test_size=0.15)

regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)
```

How do I plot the residuals of this model?

At first I tried this:

```
sns.residplot(y_pred, y_test)
```

But I'm not sure if this is actually displaying the residuals of the linear regression.  Do I have the right arguments passed to residplot?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you need to pass your x and y as arguments and `residplot` will run the regression and plot the residuals.
You can read more about `residplot` [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.residplot.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'X':np.random.randn(60),
    'Y':np.random.randn(60),
    })

sns.residplot('X','Y',data=df)
```

[image: residplot]